# How to pass a value coming from "POST" into excel or csv using Django

Tags: python, django

So, for now, I am only doing a Django project running in VirtualEnv that analyze pdf uploaded file and return a document in excel , people within the configured IP can access it without the need of installing anything, so for now I would like to keep it like that, the only problem is, in the project the result export the information into an excel file, however because I am the one activating the VE, the excel opens up in my computer and not in the user computer, do you know how I can change this? I would like to display it obviously in the current user computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think opepyxl library will work in your case . For more details , Please visit https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

```
import openpyxl
LoadExcel = openpyxl.load_workbook('File.xlsx')
ExcelContent = LoadExcel.active

ExcelContent[B1] = df[1]
LoadExcel.save
```